# Ошибка: ".addEventListener is not a function",при попытке добавить цвет элементам ,у которых есть классовый индентификатор

Tags: javascript, html

HTML

```html
<div id="signs">

    <div class="add"align="center">+</div>  
    <div class="sub"align="center">-</div>  
    <div class="mul"align="center">*</div>  
    <div class="dir" align="center">/</div>

</div>
```

JS

```
var signs=document.getElementByClassName('add');
    signs.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){

        this.style.color="yellow";

})
```

Comment: addEventListener вешается на **один** элемент, а вы за счет `getElementByClassName` выбрали **коллекцию**

Comment: И на самом деле `getElementsByClassName`?

Answer (score 3):

- Вместо `align="center"` используйте классы в `CSS`;
- Вместо `var` используйте `const` (для коллекций) или `let`;

Ваша ошибка заключалась в том, что вы обращались к коллекции (всей), а не к её элементу. Для более простого понимания, я обратился через `[0]`, но можно и в цикле прогнать.

```js
const adds = document.getElementsByClassName('add');

console.log(adds);

adds[0].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  this.style.color = "red";
})

// Пример с циклом

const greens = document.getElementsByClassName('green');

for (let i = 0; i < greens.length; i++) {
  greens[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    this.style.color = 'green';
  });
  greens[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    this.style.color = 'black';
  });
}
```

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="signs">
  <div class="add text-center">+</div>
  <div class="sub text-center green">-</div>
  <div class="mul text-center green">*</div>
  <div class="dir text-center green">/</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Может автору нужно перекрасить при наведении раз и навсегда. Иначе можно применить css `:hover`: `.green:hover { color: green }`.